# How to Solve "ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', BrokenPipeError(32, 'Broken pipe'))"

Tags: python, geospatial, geopandas, sentinel2, sentinelsat

I want to download sentinel-2 imagery for a research, using sentinelsat. However, I keep receiving `ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', BrokenPipeError(32, 'Broken pipe'))`. How do I solve this and get the data?

Here's my approach:

```
import geopandas as gpd
from sentinelsat import*

regional_bnd = "/content/MyDrive/MyDrive/shapefiles/Regional_Boundary/g_accra.shp"
shapefile = gpd.read_file(regional_bnd)
user = "my_username"
password = "my_password"
url = "https://scihub.copernicus.eu/dhus"
api = SentinelAPI(user, password, url)

aoi = None

for geom in shapefile["geometry"]:
  aoi = geom

products = api.query(
    aoi,    
    date = ("20180608", date(2018, 12, 12)),
    platformname = "Sentinel-2",
    processinglevel = "Level-2A",
    cloudcoverpercentage = (0, 30)
)
```